# Persist exception details after Transaction rollback in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to persist the exception details while rolling back the transaction in my service.

```
@Service
public class Test {

    @Transactional
    public void startTxn() {
        for (Item item : items) {
            try {
                processItem(item);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                saveErrorDetails(item, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void processItem(Item item) throws Exception {
        //business logic which persist data into tables.
    }

    public void saveErrorDetails(Item item, Exception e) {
        ErrorData errorData = new ErrorData(item.getId(), e.getMessage());
        errorRepo.save(errorData);
    }
}
```

If any exception occurs in processItem then I want to persist the exception details and rollback the transaction for the current item and continue to process other items. How can I achieve this using proper transaction management?